# How to save checked boxes in a child component in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, setstate

I have an Typescript/React app with three components:

1. **MainMenu**: user selects some cars from a list of checkboxes.
2. **CheckboxWindow**: a popup window with a checkbox list containing only cars that were selected in MainMenu
3. **CheckboxGroup**: a list of checkboxes

How can I **implement a way to save the state of the CheckboxWindow** so that if user closes and opens the window, it will still have the previously selected check boxes marked? It should also handle modifications to the selection of cars from MainMenu (say user selects more cars or deselects some cars).

```
// Parent Component ------ ------ ------ ------
interface State {
    showCheckboxWindow: boolean;
    selectedCars: string[];
}

export class MainMenu extends React.Component<Props, State> {

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showCheckboxWindow: false,
            selectedCars: [];
        };
    }
    
    public render() {
        return (
            {this.state.showCheckboxWindow && (
                <CheckboxWindow
                    setSelectedCars={(selectedCars: string[]) => this.setState({ selectedCars })}
                    selectedCars={this.state.selectedCars}
                    onCancel={() => this.setState({ showCheckboxWindow: false })}
                />
            )}
        );
    }
}


// Child Component ------ ------ ------ ------


interface Props {
    selectedCars: string[];
    setSelectedCars: (selectedCars: string[]) => void;
    onCancel: () => void;
}

export const CheckboxWindow: React.FC<Props> = props => {
    // cars selected from MainMenu
    const cars = useSelector((store: StoreState) => store.mainMenu).selectedCars;
    
    const [checkedBoxes, setCheckedBoxes] = React.useState<boolean[]>([]);

    return (
        <Window>
            <CheckboxGroup
                values={cars} // string[] values of checkboxes
                checked={checkedBoxes} // boolean[] tracks which boxes are checked
                // onChange is called when a checkbox is clicked
                onChange={(checked, value, i) => {
                    const newGroups = [...checkedBoxes];
                    newGroups[i] = !newGroups[i];
                    setCheckedBoxes(newGroups);
                                    
                    // stores string[] of selected cars in parent's state
                    // unfinished attempt at saving checked boxes when window closes
                    let selectedCars = props.selectedCars;
                    if (checked && !props.selectedCars.includes(value)) {
                        selectedCars.push(value);
                        props.setSelectedCars(selectedCars);
                    } else if (!checked && props.selectedCars.includes(value)) {
                        selectedCars = selectedCars.filter(car => car != value);
                        props.setSelectedCars(selectedCars);
                    }
                    
                }}
            />
        </Window>
    );
};

// CheckboxGroup.d.ts
import * as React from 'react';
export interface CheckboxGroupProps {
    values: string[];
    checked?: boolean[];
    onChange: (checked: boolean, value: string, i: number) => void;
}
declare const CheckboxGroup: React.FC<CheckboxGroupProps>;
export default CheckboxGroup;
```

In my code I attempted to save the selectedCars to the parent's state, but I'm not sure how to map the strings of selectedCars to the booleans of checkedBoxes or if I'm headed down the right path. I can't modify the CheckboxGroup component itself.

Comment: Can you attach a CheckboxGroup component as well?

Comment: Hoisting the state to a common ancestor is the correct approach. https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components

Comment: attached the d.ts file @mzparacha